# Error - App failed to installed

Tags: ios

My friend sent me one.app and prologs_adhoc.mobileprovision files. I have been trying for hours to upload this app to my ipod touch with version 5.0.1 4th generation. It shows up on itunes but when i try to sync with ipod, it just keep giving error mentioned above. Can anyone please guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Provisioning profile must have your device UDID.
2. The app must be built with appropriate architecture. (By default XCode 4.2 has armv7 set, and if you are trying to install it on armv6 device????? it won't)
3. Check the info.plist in the src code and check the targeted devices (if the code is written with XCode 4.2)