# iTunes Sync: 'Midhun' failed to install

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, ipod-touch

I'm developing an iOS application, for testing it I bought an iPod touch. But when I connected the device to my Mac. `Xcode` doesn't detect the device. When I tried to install `ipa` using `iTunes` it shows an error alert which says:

**`"iTunes Sync: 'Midhun' failed to install"`**

Details:

**Mac**

Mac OS X 10.7.4

**Xcode**

Xcode Version 4.6.2 with iOS 6.1

**iTunes**

iTunes 11.0.2

**iPod Touch**

Version 6.1.2

I searched this issue and got some similar issues like
[SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820718/adhoc-app-fails-to-install-on-the-device) and [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221359/error-app-failed-to-installed). But I tried every solution specified on those questions but couldn't solved my issue. Also several answers are like "delete the `Entitlement.plist`". But I'm not using `Entitlement.plist`.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Fox xcode to detect the device, did you selected the option "Use device for development" in organizer. For Itunes sync issue i would suggest you cross check your provisioning profile if device is added there ?

Comment: @Deepesh: I added it on Provisioning portal, need to check the organizer for that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the issue. I didn't clicked the "**Use for Development**" option.
That's why the ipa was failed to install on that device, even though the device Id is added to the provisioning profile.

[image: Use for Development]